# Making an array of three mildly related classes

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, interface

I'm making a game in Java for my AP Computer science project. It is played on a game board, where you have a border, inner spaces, and then a special type of inner space. The three are distinct, and each have unique behaviors, but they are all connected as in that they are all on the game board.

The spaces are going to be constant once they are made -- the characters will handle doing all the moving and the appropriate behavior for whatever space they are on.

The goal is to have all of these in a two dimensional array, and I'm not sure how as to best approach it. I have considered the following things

1. Use an empty or nearly empty interface or abstract class where the regular space and special space inherit from an abstract space class and both the space class and the border class implement the interface or extend the parent abstract class
2. Declare them all as the same type and define different behaviors based upon whatever type it is.
3. Make it a two dimensional array list with `Object` as the type.

All of these seem a bit hackish. What would be an appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: Why does the border have to be any kind of class at all?

Comment: Because when the character is on the border, it acts differently than on a regular square

Comment: Are all three places where a character can be? If so, don't they have methods related to characters arriving, leaving, or being there that should be defined in their common interface?

Comment: The character will handle leaving and moving.

Answer (score 1):

#1 should definitely be your go-to option, and its not hackish at all. I'de probably go with some sort of abstract class called `BoardSquare` or something, and have everything inherit from that.

The fact that a class is near-empty, or even empty is not inherently bad (though if the class is empty it should really be an interface). One of the major motivations behind the implementations of lambdas in Java 8 were classes/interfaces that were just a wrapper around one function (consider the [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or the [closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)). Moreover, who says it should be that empty? I could think of a couple of potentially common methods: `Square.moveTo()`, `moveFrom()`, `actOn()`, `convert()`, `status()` `toString()`, etc.

#2 and #3 *would* work, and aren't technically hackish, but they make your code very hard to maintain/upgrade. What happens when you add a new square type? What happens when you want to change the behavior of one, but not others? etc.

Comment: An empty class nearly always is bad; if there's no state (or behavior, pre-Java 8) to inherit, it should be an interface instead.

Comment: @chrylis You are right, I thought that but I didnt put it down.